# How to understand Goldstein's derivation of the Infinitesimal Rotation Matrix?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

[image: Goldstein infinitesimal rotation page 168]

I can't seem to follow the chain of reasoning that leads to equation 4-100). Can anybody please help me to understand that why under infinitesimal rotation x1 transforms in the way as shown ?

This is from Goldstein's Classical Mechanics page chapter 5 and page 168 on the Kinematics of Rigid body motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose a finite rotation around x axis. The rotation matrix is:

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos(\theta_1) & sin(\theta_1)\\
0 & -sin(\theta_1) & cos(\theta_1)
\end{vmatrix}

Now a rotation around y axis:

\begin{vmatrix}
cos(\theta_2) & 0 & -sin(\theta_2)\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
sin(\theta_2) & 0 & cos(\theta_2)
\end{vmatrix}

Finally a rotation around z axis:

\begin{vmatrix}
cos(\theta_3) & sin(\theta_3) & 0\\
-sin(\theta_3) & cos(\theta_3) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}

If the rotations are infinitesimal, $cos(\theta_i)\sim 1$ and $sin(\theta_i) \sim \theta_i$.

If we want now a composite infinitesimal rotation, we multiply that matrices, following that approximations, and disregarding the products of $\theta_i*\theta_j$ that are second order infinitesimals.

We get:

\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \theta_3 & -\theta_2\\
-\theta_3 & 1 & -\theta_1\\
\theta_2 & -\theta_1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}

If we use that matrix to transform a vector:
$$
 \begin{vmatrix} x^{'}_1 \\ x^{'}_2 \\x^{'}_3 \end{vmatrix}  = \begin{vmatrix}
1 & \theta_3 & -\theta_2\\
-\theta_3 & 1 & -\theta_1\\
\theta_2 & -\theta_1 & 1
\end{vmatrix} \times  \begin{vmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{vmatrix} 
$$

We have the same expression from the book, except that $\epsilon_{ij} = 0$ if $i = j$

Comment: But the author didn't say $\epsilon_{ij}=0$ for $i=j$

Comment: @Kashmiri I don't have the book, so I don't know what it is written there except by what was copied by the OP.

Comment: I agree with you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have your point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. If you do a traslation over the x axis, the $x'_1$ would be $x'_1=x_1+a$ but if the traslation is infinitesimal you will have $x'_1=x_1+\varepsilon x_1$.

If you have a rotation, you can extrapolate from the traslational movement, now you have 3 traslations in space, each one infinitesimal for $x_1,x_2,x_3$:

$$x'_1=x_1+\varepsilon_{11} x_1+\varepsilon_{12} x_2+\varepsilon_{13} x_3$$

Comment: I can't understand  how we can extrapolate translation to rotation and moreover why these changes are proportional to the coordinates itself.

Comment: In case of translation if I shift the x axis by dx then the coordinate also changes by dx and isn't proportional to the original coordinates.